# In java how to replace substring in a string only if it is at starting position

Tags: java, string

i want to replcae "Demo" from  "DemoString"  with other substring,but only if "Demo" is present at the starting of string.No replacement will be in case of "StringDemo".

Comment: `^Demo` use this regex and then replace the string demo with the chars you want.

Comment: String str ="DemoString";
    String newString =str;
    if(str.startsWith("Demo")){
        newString= str.replace("Demo","Another");
    }

Comment: @Shree this would replace `Demo` in `DemofooDemo`

Comment: Agree . But Question states that If starting position has "Demo" It should replace Demo Substring ... it doesnt talk what if Demo is at start and End. Surely we can use **ReplaceFirst** Method of String if we have to avoid.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean?

```
String text = ...
String text2 = text.replaceAll("^Demo", "NotDemo");
```

For regular expressions the `^` only matches the start of the string.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack Overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: I would agree; document how this code answers the question.

Answer (score 5):

check condition if the string starts with the key then replace the first key with the desired key like below:

```
String string = "demo string string demo";

if (string.startsWith("demo")) {
    System.out.println(string.replaceFirst("demo", "xyz"));
}
```

output:

```
xyz string string demo
```

**Update:**

As we are using replaceFirst() there is no need of adding condition we can directly call the method to replace the string

```
System.out.println(string.replaceFirst("^demo", "xyz"));
```

Comment: The second part of your answer will work incorrectly for this input: "string string demo" . It will produce "string string". You should use string.replaceFirst("^demo", "xyz"). ^ matched the beginning of the string.

Comment: @AlexMisiulia thanks for pointing it out, corrected nw...

Comment: Using `replaceAll` and `replaceFirst` isn't always ideal, since they interpret the first argument as a regular expression. This can be quite unexpected, especially if the string can contain something that's not alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this short example:

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

    String s = "DemoString StringDemo DemoString";

    String[] str = s.split(" ");

    for(String ss : str)
    {
        int index = ss.indexOf("Demo"); //check if "Demo" is at the start of the string
        if(index == 0)
        {
            ss = ss.replace("Demo","Demo2");
        }
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
 }
}
```

Output:
Demo2String StringDemo Demo2String

Comment: But `DemoStringDemo` would be replaced to `Demo2StringDemo2`, right?

Comment: yes, it would. since it starts with Demo. You could use `replaceFirst()` instead of `replace()`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
String myline = line.replaceAll("^[Dd][eE][mM][Oo]", "");
```

Comment: don't complex the things `"^(?i)demo"`

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack Overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.